# How can I make resistance surfaces in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

So I want to build a model for species distribution regarding a species of land snail. I had the idea to build resistance surfaces in order to account for the limited dispersal capabilities that it has. I currently possess: a DEM of the area, and additional layers of the slope and the terrain ruggedness index. How can I use the above to make these surfaces? I cant seem to find a reliable guide for it so I hope some of you people know!

Comment: Although I accepted the answer provided by @markusN, I still want to hear any other recommendations. Feel free to recommend other solutions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look at the GRASS GIS module [r.walk](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/r.walk.html): it creates a raster map showing the anisotropic cumulative cost of moving between different geographic locations on an input raster map whose cell category values represent cost. Essentially, you can define the moving speed in accordance to slope etc.

In QGIS, it is available under Processing > Toolboxes > GRASS GIS.